# Is it possible to port HDMI audio and VGA video from one computer through a monitor and speaker simultaneously?

Tags: windows-7, audio, video, hdmi, vga

I have a Yamaha Home Theater System that I connect to my Windows 7 PC (via HDMI) for playing audio. My TV is broken and I can only use my monitor to display video. This monitor does not have HDMI and only has VGA. Is it possible to have both VGA and HDMI plugged into my PC with HDMI porting audio through to the home theater system and VGA porting video through the monitor simultaneously? (I have already tried running an auxiliary cable from my PC to the theater system, but it doesn't get the same sound quality as the HDMI would).

Comment: Never tried it, usually you need a dual head video card to use both ports, hdmi sound is configured in Sound properties>Playback tab.

Comment: Instead of HDMI, try to connect the PC to the receiver using a digital multi-channel audio output.  This would be a S/PDIF port, either a Toslink optical port or an orange RCA (or 3.5mm) port for coax.

Comment: I am going to invest in dual head video card so I can use both ports. Until then, I'll stick with just using S/PDIF for the audio. Thank you for all of the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: It is not possible to route HDMI for audio and VGA for video on one computer, unless there is some sort of software that you can use to independently control the audio and video input or you have a dual head video card.